# How to reload Angular app (All Pages) after every few seconds

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express

I'm currently working on Angular,Mongodb and nodejs as backend. But problem is whenever I add something like image or any entry I have to refresh the angular page to show the changes.
So is there any way to automatically reload every page of an angular app?

Also I would like to add that it's a group project so if another partner enter any image (image path) into data from his/her side I dont get the image as image doesn't not existed in my laptop and visa versa.
Is there any other way to reflect the image both the side even if it doesn't exist in each other's memory ?

Comment: from where are you adding new object?  If client you don't need to refresh page. You just refresh your data connected to html. If you add this from backend then use websockets, signalR technologies to detect changes from backend

Comment: You could try with sockets. It helps to transfer data in real time.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about WebSockets and where to put it so that all the pages can reload itself? (Adding data to backend)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always add a reload function on a timer:

```
setTimeout(window.location.reload.bind(window.location), 250);
```

But I would argue that this method isn't conducive to a good user experience though - window reloads are jarring.

A better option would be to create an observable bound to changes in collections on your database, and reset the image holder HTML based on events from that observable.